# Moment.js isBefore() not working when checking for if before 12pm/Noon

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js to handle some date labeling on the front-end. I've come across an obscure scenario and would like the MomentJS experts to course-correct me, please.

Consider the following implementation with a string value passed in, `"2018-08-28T20:21:56"`

Do note, the aforementioned date string and the add minute `600` are provided dynamically from the back-end.

```
let dateTitle;

// Before setting date label, compare enddate with endoffset against 12pm
let endCutOff = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56").add(600, 'm');
let isBeforeNoon = moment(endCutOff).isBefore(moment({ hour: 12, minute: 0 }));

if ( isBeforeNoon ) {
    // Credit previous day if user ended before noon.
    dateTitle = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56")
    .add(600, 'm')
    .local()
    .subtract(1, 'd')
    .format('MMMM D, YYYY');
} else {
    // Credit that very day if after 12pm.
    dateTitle = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56")
    .add(600, 'm')
    .local()
    .format('MMMM D, YYYY');
}
```

This outputs correctly as **"August 28, 2018"**

However, perform the same operation again with string value passed in, `"2018-08-29T20:43:58"` and you'll see that this outputs as **"August 30, 2018"**.

It should be **"August 29, 2018"**.

I recognize the obvious in that `isBeforeNoon` is true the first round and false the next. But an explanation as to why and how to fix it is where I need your expertise. I suspect it has to do with the date string format being passed but that's just a notion so far.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, the problem is caused by the date component of `moment({ hour: 12, minute: 0 })` defaulting to "today's calendar date".

By default, `.isBefore()` accounts for both time **and the date** of moment instances being compared.

This therefore means that `isBeforeNoon` is decided on the date of  `endCutOff` and the current calendar date (which is obviously always changing).

Perhaps you could do the following:

```
let endCutOff = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56").add(600, 'm');

// Create a copy of endCutOff to aquire the date from endCutOff, and set
// hour/minute accordingly
let momentForIsBefore = endCutOff.clone().hour(12).minute(0).second(0); 
let isBeforeNoon = moment(endCutOff).isBefore(momentForIsBefore);

if ( isBeforeNoon ) {
    // Credit previous day if user ended before noon.
    dateTitle = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56")
    .add(600, 'm')
    .local()
    .subtract(1, 'd')
    .format('MMMM D, YYYY');
} else {
    // Credit that very day if after 12pm.
    dateTitle = moment("2018-08-28T20:21:56")
    .add(600, 'm')
    .local()
    .format('MMMM D, YYYY');
}
```

Hope this helps!